# Pass variable IP address to if else

Tags: text-processing, command-line, variable

I have this command:

```
ptr=`host $hostname`
```

Which results in this:

```
test.tester.test has address 192.168.1.1
```

This Works!

What I want now is to extract only the IP address (192.168.1.1), pass it 
to the variable $myptr and run the following command:

```
if $myptr | sed -n '/\(\(1\?[0-9][0-9]\?\|2[0-4][0-9]\|25[0-5]\)\.\)\{3\}\(1\?[0-9][0-9]\?\|2[0-4][0-9]\|25[0-5]\)/p' ; then
   host $myptr
else
   echo "No PTR Record found"
fi
```

But it does not work. Please help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need any extravagant text processing on the output of `host`, you can just use `dig +short` to get only the IP address (and do the required reverse lookup on the IP).

```
dig +short "$hostname"
```

e.g.

```
ip="$(dig +short "$hostname")"
host "$ip"
```

Or directly:

```
host "$(dig +short "$hostname")"
```

Comment: Legend, Thank you... Chasing my own tail there...

Answer (score 0):

To extract ip you can awk it for example:

```
ptr=`host $hostname | awk '/has address/ {print $NF}'`
```

- **/has address/** mach only line that has this string as host can return much more for you. Try google for example.
- **print $NF** - NF is awk's variable returning number of fields, so $NF points to last field.

Then you could use grep and check it's return code (sed will return 0 regardles if it will find your regexp or not. So doing something like this would work:

```
echo $ptr | egrep "your pattern"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "This Works"
fi
```

But you could simply check if **$ptr** contains an output. If host command won't find anything **$ptr** will be empty, so:

```
if [ -n $ptr ]; then
    echo "Works"
else 
    echo "Not found :("
fi
```

Take a look at **man test**:

```
-n STRING
          the length of STRING is nonzero
-z STRING
          the length of STRING is zero
```